# Hide WooCommerce data from other admins in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have to create an admin user for a marketing company in my Wordpress website but I do not want them to have access to WooCommerce data. In other words, they should not be gain information regarding sales data, customer names, email, address and so on. However, they need to have access to themes and plugins.

Is there a way to hide WooCommerce data from admin view or create a user account with all the admin privileges except WooCommerce access?

Please help,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new role in code and add specific capabilities to it. But it's much easier to use a *role editor* plugin like *[User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)*

Just create a new role and assign the capabilities you want while leaving out those of Woocommerce.